# Android make whole tablerow clickable

Tags: java, android, tablerow, clickable

I have a litte problem. 
I want to create a Table with clickable TableRows.
Most of this works fine, but the OnClickListener does not work for the whole Tablerow.
The TableRow is not clickable where the vertical Scrollview Element is.
Is there a way to set a clicklistener for the whole Row?

Here a code snippet from the activity:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <anzahl; i++) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.pnunterhaltungslist, null);
        TextView UnterhaltungsBetreff = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Unterhaltungsbetreff);
        TextView UnterhaltungsBeteiligte = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Unterhaltungvon);
        TextView UnterhaltungsUhrzeit = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Uhrzeit);
        TextView UnterhaltungsDatum = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Datum);
        row.setId(1000+i);
        row.setClickable(true);
        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       Intent myIntent = new Intent(PNs.this, Main.class);
                                       PNs.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                                   }
                               });
        UnterhaltungsBetreff.setText(Unterhaltungslist.get(i * 4 + 4) + "  ");
        UnterhaltungsBeteiligte.setText(Unterhaltungslist.get(i*4+2)+"  ");
        Date Datum = new Date(Integer.parseInt(Unterhaltungslist.get(i*4+3))*1000L);
        DateFormat Datumf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
        DateFormat Zeitf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        UnterhaltungsUhrzeit.setText(Zeitf.format(Datum));
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        long todayInMillis = c.getTimeInMillis();

        if(todayInMillis - (Integer.parseInt(Unterhaltungslist.get(i*4+3))*1000L)<= 0){
            UnterhaltungsDatum.setText("Heute");

        }
        else if ((Integer.parseInt(Unterhaltungslist.get(i*4+3))*1000L) - (todayInMillis- 86400000) >= 0){
            UnterhaltungsDatum.setText("Gestern");
        }
        else{
            UnterhaltungsDatum.setText(Datumf.format(Datum));
        }
        Unterhalttable.addView(row,i);
    }
}
```

Here the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
    android:id="@+id/one">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Unterhaltungrelativlayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="12:00"
            android:id="@+id/Uhrzeit"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/horizontalScrollView3"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="heute"
            android:id="@+id/Datum"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Uhrzeit"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#ff363132"
            android:id="@+id/borderline"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView3" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Uhrzeit"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Uhrzeit"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/relativlayout1">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Unterhaltung-Beteiligte"
                    android:id="@+id/Unterhaltungvon"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/Unterhaltungsbetreff"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Unterhaltungs-Betref blabasdkasnfdsadhfhsadfsadgsadögh"
                    android:id="@+id/Unterhaltungsbetreff"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/verlaufpn"
            android:id="@+id/borderline2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Uhrzeit"
            android:paddingTop="-2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="-3dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/borderline"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/horizontalScrollView3"/>

          </RelativeLayout>

</TableRow>
```

Picture : (green clickable / red not clickable)
http://abload.de/img/screenshot_2014-09-17lpu6s.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<TableRow
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onTableRowClick"
    android:id="@+id/one">
```

Then in your activity, create the function "onTableRowClick" and it will be called when the layout is clicked.

Comment: Sorry but the result is the same